# Is this model safe with pthreads?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, pthreads

I have two threads (main and background), they can communicate through a socket pair. The main thread waits to read from the socket. The background thread loads and processes a file, then it should send that data to the main thread.

Is it a good idea to send just the pointer from the background thread through the socket? Can I be sure that all data will be in the correct state once I receive the pointer to it on the main thread?

I am asking this, because I am wondering if there could be any issues with memory caching in the processor, since the background thread may be running on a different core.

I am working on iOS and OS X, and I can integrate waiting on a socket into the run loop (using CFSocket).

I know that using GCD may be better, but I want to learn pthreads.

Comment: Why would you use threads rather than processes when you're sharing the data explicitly by sending it via a socket? If you're using threads, shared memory is the natural way to communicate.

Comment: @EOF This is all because of iOS apps, all of them have a run loop on the main thread. That run loop can be configured to wait on a socket while also being able to get notifications about UI interactions. Waiting for a mutex can not be configured in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read()` and `write()` are not included in the POSIX list of ["functions that synchronize memory"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11), so technically this is not guaranteed to work by POSIX.

You would need to use a POSIX synchronisation function - for example, `pthread_barrier_wait()` might be appropriate here (the sending function executes the barrier after storing the data and publishing the pointer; the receiving function executes the barrier before reading the data).